# SPIFFS Upload Failed Error Code -10010 While uploading files to ESP8266

Tags: css, esp8266, spiffs

I have an ESP8266, WEMOS D1 Mini to be exact , im using a Arduino IDE and the plugin to upload a data to the ESP8266
heres the error messages :

```
[SPIFFS] data    : C:\WASP-master\data
[SPIFFS] size    : 3048
[SPIFFS] page    : 256
[SPIFFS] block   : 8192
/css/bootstr..m.css.map
/css/bootstr.min.css
/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
/favicon.ico
/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
/index.html
/js/bootstrap.min.js
/js/jquery.min.js
/js/npm.js
/rules.json
SPIFFS_write error(-10010): unknown
error adding file!
Error for adding content from css!
SPIFFS_write error(-10010): unknown
error adding file!
Error for adding content from fonts!
[SPIFFS] upload  : C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_916713/WASP-master.spiffs.bin
[SPIFFS] address  : 0x100000
[SPIFFS] reset    : --before default_reset --after hard_reset
[SPIFFS] port     : COM4
[SPIFFS] speed    : 921600
[SPIFFS] python   : C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1\python3.exe
[SPIFFS] uploader : C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\tools\upload.py

esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM4
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 8c:aa:b5:7a:8b:80
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 3121152 bytes to 227763...
Wrote 3121152 bytes (227763 compressed) at 0x00100000 in 12.8 seconds (effective 1951.0 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

it looks like its not having any problem uploading other file in the folder, only files in the css and fonts folder thats failed.

is there anything i can do to resolve this problem ?
Thank you

Comment: Is there enough space for all of those files? Which partition scheme did you select? Your spiffs image is quite large, maybe too large.

Comment: FyI: the datafolder gets compiled/compressed to a spiffs image which then gets uploaded. In your case, the first step already fails.

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering , by any chance is there any way to check the available storage for the files ? , and im quite unsure which partition scheme i used , i simply make the folder and upload it as i didnt make changes to the settings.

Comment: are you sure those two files `/css/bootstr..m.css.map`, and `/css/bootstr.min.css` existed in your `data/` folder?

Comment: yes I'm positive its there @hcheung

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a limitation on SPIFFS file name size of 32 bytes (including starting slash and zero at the end)

```
/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map        --> 32 bytes
/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot --> 39 bytes
```

See documentation https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/filesystem.rst#spiffs-file-system-limitations

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html#filesystem